# Can anyone tell me type of grapes these are?

Tags: identification, fruits, grape-vine

I happen to have these grapes here in India with me, no one seems to know the name of this grape.
It has got a thick skin and thick gelatinous pulp.

[image: Bunch of red grapes]

Comment: Do you have pictures of the leaves or the whole plant as well maybe?

Comment: @BenceKaulics no, unfortunately they do not sell it with leaves :(

Comment: @BenceKaulics any similar species would help, I can then cross reference those with the characteristics.

Comment: Check if the skin comes off easily, and if the seeds are bitter. This will help with identification.

Comment: @PolypipeWrangler there are no seeds and yes the skin comes off easily.

Comment: My answer may be wrong. Bangalore Blue has seeds, but can have two crops per year. Sharam Seedless is a clone of Kishmish Chorni. If someone can find out if this variety is derived from V. labrusca that would mostly identify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like [Bangalore Blue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bangalore_Blue), except your sample is seedless.

That is commonly grown in India.

Grapes in the species  *Vitis labrusca*, or crossed with them have the  slip-skin characteristic where the skin detaches easily.

Comment: You may be right, but I cannot up-vote or mark the answer as accepted before I verify it.
Oh by the way what if the skin did not come off easily ?

Comment: If skin attached to flesh then I think that it is any other vitus species (e.g vinifera).

Answer (score 2):

The black-purple colour, with seedless characteristic and oval shape correspond with the Sharad Seedless variety, found in Maharashtra state. You might look to see if they come in possibly large bunches, another characteristic of the vine.

There is a [Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/KisanJankariAbhiyanKIJA/photos/black-grape-varieties-such-as-sharad-seedless-have-bluish-black-berriesit-is-a-c/1449679475049024/) that claims that Sharad Seedless is a clonal variety of [Kishmish Chernyi](https://www.vivc.de/index.php?r=passport%2Fview&id=6256) which apparently is a *Vitis vinifera*.